# How do I get values from a PHP array to a Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, php

So I am currently doing some coding for the website of someone of my outer family and I had to create a bar chart and now I need to fill it with data from their SQL-Database. First I just echo'd the array like this:

PHP:

```
<?php
$exampleArray = ["212", "33", "7"]
?>
```

and JS:

```
<script> var jExampleArray = <? echo json_encode($exampleArray);?>;  </script>
```

And then I used jExampleArray in my bar chart code. Now I was very happy but the they say that it needs to be more secure (it involves their company) and I have to find a way to make sure nobody can just see the data while looking through the code on the page. I thought about using Ajax and what not but it just didn't work for me. I got it to alert me the array, but was not able to fill a Javascript array with it.

I never did stuff with JS, PHP oder SQL before and only learned Java in school so I am pretty clueless and most of the stuff I did was with help of the Internet. Luckily I managed to at least understand the code I wrote/copied.

Edit: [] for a JS array not {}

Comment: ExampleArray is not an array.

Comment: Also, whilst it may not be visible in 'View Source', a simple F12 (Developer Console) in IE/Chrome will allow them to see the resulting JS code, objects, data.

Comment: For it to be an array, It should be `$exampleArray = ["212", "33", "7"]`;

Comment: Woops sorry. Tried to type this without looking at my normal code to practise it.

Comment: for the future, copy the _exact_ code from your IDE

Comment: are you using Google Charts? If yes ( having read the bit about security etc ) then perhaps using `fusiontables` might be a suitable option

Comment: I am actually using Chart code from a website and modified it slightly to fit what I want. I wanted to use JCharts or something in that direction but the Chef said no to open source since you don't know if they'll decide to just stop it one day.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for creating the PHP array is incorrect.

Use the function `json_encode` to transform PHP arrays into Javascript arrays and objects.

```
<?php

$arr = ['hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar'];
$obj = ['hello' => 'world', 'foo' => 'bar'];

echo 'var Array = ' . json_encode($arr) . PHP_EOL .
     'var Obj = ' . json_encode($obj, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) . PHP_EOL;
```

Will result in the following:

```
var Array = ["hello","world","foo","bar"]
var Obj = {"hello":"world","foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. It always said there is something wrong with the first line $arr = .....

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Find out by creating a file that is just `echo phpversion()`. If it is less than 5.4, you need to create arrays using `$arr = array('hello', etc');`

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I am actually using 5.2

Comment: I will have to. But I'll only be here for about 8 other days.

This said. I tried it with this and it now says "var ArrayTest = ['hello, 'test', 'wow'] (used them for a test). Now is there a way I can let JS output it by using document.write()?

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code to show how you might accomplish the stated goal

```
$data=array();
while( $rs=$db->fetch() ){
    $data[]=array(
        'field_1'   =>  $rs->field_1,
        'field_2'   =>  $rs->field_2,
        'field_3'   =>  $rs->field_3
    );
}

$json=json_encode( $data );


<script>
    <?php
        echo "var jExampleArray={$json};";
    ?>
    /* rest of barchart code */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP array is available at page load use:

```
<?php
$phpArray = array('data1' => 2, 'data2' => 3);
?>
<script>var arr = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;</script>
```

To retrieve PHP array in JS after page load using ajax:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(responseArray);
```

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse(responseArray);` wouldn't work

Comment: @LucaKiebel JSON.parse is to convert raw text into JS array (if formatted correctly). Updated the thread specifying the method is to be used with ajax response.